# Is there a way to access a class object's information based on a user's input?

Tags: c++

hope this hasn't been answered before, looked around and couldn't find it.  Was wondering how to to access a specific class object based on a users input.  Sort of in a similar way that you would access the value of a  specific index of an array based on the user's input and going to that index.

I'm not entirely sure what I would do seeing as there isn't an accessible integer like there is in an array.  Relatively new to programming so sorry if something I have said doesn't make sense.

```cpp
class Hams {
public:
    string name;
};

int main()
{
    int userNum;

    Hams ham1;
    ham1.name = "Porky";

    Hams ham2;
    ham2.name = "Wilbur";

    Hams ham3;
    ham3.name = "Piglet";

    cout << "Enter num of pig you want to know the name of: ";
    cin >> userNum;


    //Output the correct name
}
```

If the user enters in 3, then the output should be "Piglet".

```cpp
cout << ham(userNum).name << endl;
```

I know this code isn't correct but its how I can best express what I'm trying to do.

Is there a way to do this or something similar to it other than an if statement like below?

```cpp
if (userNum == 3) {
print(ham3.name);
}
```

Comment: Yes if you place all 3 hams inside some other class and then write your own function for the class like GetMemberValue( int index ) with a big switch - case statement.  That's if all 3 pigs were in * 1 * class object not separate class object.  No if the class objects are not lumped together inside another class.  But as the answer below and comments say what you really want is a std::array or std::vector of either std::string or of Hams objects.

Comment: Sounds like you want an array

Comment: In general when you find yourself making sequentially numbered variable names, stop and ask yourself "Would an array would fit better here?"

Comment: OP could conceivably not know about the switch statement. I wouldn't say that it would be better than the array but that might be new and interesting information for them.

Comment: @QuinnMortimer Switch statements are generally used for deciding code flow paths, not for indexing into a known 'array' of elements. But I agree, knowing how to use switch statements is a powerful skill, especially when writing state machines.

Comment: @AlexHodges I only say that because the way I read the question the OP knows they could use an array and wants to consider another option. On the fence about writing an answer suggesting the switch statement here because I don't know if it has more than curiosity value here.

Comment: Dave's comment combined with a solution provided by Alex clears this up for me.  Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
    std::array<std::string, 3> pigs = {"Porky", "Wilbur", "Piglet"};

    int userNum;
    std::cout << "Enter num of pig you want to know the name of: ";
    std::cin >> userNum;

    std::cout << pigs[userNum-1] << std::endl;
```

EDIT* To be more exact to your use case, here is another example:

```
class Hams {
  public:
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{

    std::array<Hams, 3> pigs = {"Porky", "Wilbur", "Piglet"};

    int userNum;
    std::cout << "Enter num of pig you want to know the name of: ";
    std::cin >> userNum;

    std::cout << pigs[userNum-1].name << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Also, if you want a variable size of Hams at runtime, use a std::vector<>

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the tips on writing a better answer!

Comment: Ok this makes sense to me and is essentially what I'm looking for.  A little more complicated than I was hoping it would be but I guess thats the nature of programming.  Thank you!